# How to load cookies from another domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

Say I have two apps on two different domains. One app is an online store, and another app is affiliate admin panel.

The task is: if the user is affiliate, show him a special header.

The question: how can I go and ask my affiliate admin panel if my user is logged in there? I cannot just make an async call, because the cookies are not returned this way. Do I have to use iframe or is there another way?

Comment: http://www.opentracker.net/article/third-party-cookies-vs-first-party-cookies, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Privacy_and_third-party_cookies

Comment: Can't you send a request to the admin domain via javascript. The cookie on the admin domain need to have the right permission thought

Answer (score 1):

Configure a special endpoint on admin panel server (running nginx):

```
location /hack_cookie {
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    if ($http_referer ~* (your_app_domain)) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'your_cookie,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-  Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        add_header  your_cookie $cookie_your_cookie;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        return 200 'Ok';
    }
}
```

Then in your app:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://www.admin_panel_domian.com/hack_cookie', false);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.send();
req.onload = function(){
    var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders();
}
```

Now just parse `headers` string which will look like this:

```
date: Tue, 17 May 2016 06:46:52 GMT
server: nginx/1.10.0
access-control-max-age: 1728000
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
content-type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
status: 200
access-control-allow-credentials: true
your_cookie: fancyjohn
access-control-allow-headers: your_cookie,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
content-length: 2
```